# Redirection to a GET after a PUT in Rails (status: 303) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 5.1, I'm doing a PUT, and trying to redirect on a certain error:

```
  rescue_from ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken do
    redirect_to new_user_session_url, status: 303 and return
  end
```

The docs show that status: 303 should make the redirect_to be called as a GET, but it's still a PUT.

How can I make this redirect as a GET?

Thanks

Comment: In the docs (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) I see that the 303 work-around is for XHR requests. Is that your context? Did you try leaving off the `status` altogether?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. It tries to do a PUT redirect which also doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sure you've thought of this, but is the `new_user_session` route restricted to GET only?

Comment: Yes, and I tried create a PUT route for that path too, and that didn't work either, which surprised me.

Comment: So is this AJAX or browser call in your case?

Comment: @TarunLalwani AJAX

Comment: With HTTP you can only redirect to a GET request. My guess is that you are tripping over another route or something like that.  Best way to debug would be to post the relevant results of `rake routes` and the portion of your server log that is also relevant.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it seems it would be a HTML based redirect which Rails is doing, can you check in Network tab as to what is the response of your first AJAX call and what happens afterwards?

Comment: dumb question but are you positive you're dropping into the rescue_from block and that the redirect isn't happening elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it with Ajax, your request is processing as JS , then your redirect shouldn't work, because you need yo get a response in your complete through Ajax call.

Finally, you should redirect within the complete callback sending the URL with your controller.

I Hope that helps you

Answer (score 1):

I could make `PUT` redirect work in `browser` and in `curl`

```
# Gemfiile
gem 'rails'
gem 'pry'
gem 'puma'


# app.rb
require 'rails'
require 'action_controller'
require 'rack/handler/puma'

class InvalidAuthenticityToken < StandardError
end

# HelloController
class HelloController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render inline: '
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
    '
  end

  def update
    raise InvalidAuthenticityToken
  end

  def redirect
    render plain: 'you are redirected'
  end

  rescue_from InvalidAuthenticityToken do
    redirect_to '/you_are_redirected'
  end
end

class MyApp < Rails::Application
end

app = MyApp.new
app.config.secret_key_base = 'my-secret'
app.initialize!
app.routes.draw do
  get '/' => 'hello#index'
  get '/you_are_redirected' => 'hello#redirect'
  put '/' => 'hello#update'
  put '/you_are_redirected' => 'hello#redirect'
  post '/you_are_redirected' => 'hello#redirect' # for browser request
end

Rack::Handler::Puma.run app
```

To run it

```
bundle
bundle exec ruby app.rb
```

visit `localhost:9292` or

```
curl -X PUT localhost:9292 -L

you are redirected%
```

I wish it helped

Answer (score 1):

You're request isn't http so the status will not work. Change your redirect to the following:  `render :js => "window.location = '/users/signup'"` or whatever yournew_user_session_path` url is.